# Spamassassin public corpus

Tags: spam

I selfhost my mail server and have earlier downloaded Spamassassin corpus from http://artinvoice.hu/spam to have a head start on the bayes learning.

The artinvoice.hu site is down and has been for weeks.
Are there any known good alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

There is also Untroubled.org,
They tend to publish montly spam as well.

http://untroubled.org/spam/

Answer (score 0):

Apache's own corpus is fine but old https://spamassassin.apache.org/old/publiccorpus/

There's also the Enron set with plenty of spam and ham http://www2.aueb.gr/users/ion/data/enron-spam/